# To find domain of $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left\{x\right\}-x^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions

Find domain of $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left\{x\right\}-x^2}}$$ where $\left\{x\right\}$ is Fractional part function.  I tried as follows:

$$\left\{x\right\} \gt x^2$$ so

$$x-\left[x \right] \gt x^2$$  Or

$$x^2-x+\left[x\right] \lt 0$$

How to proceed further?

Comment: I think you should have $\ge$ instead of $\gt$.

Comment: @Frpzzd It should be $>$, since the square root resides in the denominator of the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $0\le\{x\}<1$ and  $x^2<\{x\}<1\implies-1<x<1$

If $0\le x<1, \{x\}=x,$  so we need $x>x^2\iff x(x-1)<0\iff 0<x<1$

Iff $-1<x<0, \{x\}=1+x$

Comment: It does not work for $x=-0.9$...

Comment: @Frpzzd, $$-0.9=-1+(1-0.9)$$  right?

Comment: If you use the identity $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$, then you see that at $x=-0.9$, we get that $\{x\}-x^2$ is $0.1-0.81$ which is negative.

Comment: @Frpzzd if $x \in (-1 \:\: 0)$ then $x^2 \lt 1+x$ that is $x^2-x-1 \lt 0$ so essentially $x \in (\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \:\: 0)$ in which $-0.9$ is absent

Comment: @Frpzzd,   By your definition what $$\lfloor -0.9\rfloor=?$$

Comment: $\lfloor -0.9\rfloor=-1$

Comment: @Frpzzd, Then $$\{-0.9\}=1-0.9$$ right?

Comment: No. By my definition $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$, $\{0.9\}=-0.9-\lfloor -0.9\rfloor=-0.9-(-1)=-0.9+1=0.1$

Comment: @Frpzzd, Have I said anything different ? :)

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that $x=-0.9$ is not in the domain, because $\{-0.9\}-(0.9)^2$ is negative, making $\sqrt{\{-0.9\}-(0.9)^2}$ nonreal.

Comment: @Frpzzd, I didn't say so. I left that part for the OP

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=a+b$ for some $a\in\mathbb{Z}\quad b\in\mathbb{R},\quad0\leq b<1$

Then we require $$b\geq (a+b)^2\implies (a+b+\sqrt{b})(a+b-\sqrt{b})\leq 0$$

Critical points: $a_1=-b-\sqrt{b}$ and $a_2=-b+\sqrt{b}$

Note that $0\leq b<1\implies \sqrt{b}>b>0$

So then $a_2>0>a_1$

If we take $a=-b$, then $b\geq 0$. So the interval we're after is

$-b-\sqrt{b}<a<-b+\sqrt{b}$

Not sure if this answer goes anywhere, posted it as community wiki to see if someone thinks it does.